# How can I fix/patch a small hole in an LCD monitor?

Tags: display, tv, repair

I’ve had this tiny little hole in my LCD panel for a couple years now, and it’s been bothering me.  It must have been hit by someone not paying attention or during a move.

- It is not dead/stuck pixels.
- The screen does not have any glass.
- There is a physical jabbed hole in the plastic film layer that catches the light
- There is no damage to the pixels, just a bright spot where light gets through and dark around the edges of the tiny hole (about 4x2 pixels, 1mm wide)

Is there an at-home way to repair the plastic film material, or at least make it less obvious?

When looking it up I find lots of scratched screen solutions, but this isn’t a scratch, and scratches don’t really show on this screen, so micro-scratches are not an issue.

I’m hoping for a way to fill in or perhaps heat the material and massage it back into place without damaging the screen. The material is clearly displaced, where the edges are high around the hole.

[image]

Comment: That's not tiny. That's a pretty major failure by the looks of things. A small issue is a bright pixel. That looks like a great big region of damage.

Comment: It's only 1mm(4px) wide, by 0.5mm(2px) tall. lol, my second screen has pixels twice the size of my main.  It's not even visible when i look at the centre of my screen.

Comment: If the monitor's still working, don't mess with it. You will get what you truly desire, a larger patch of non-working stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a year, once again being exposed to polarization films, i clued into the fact that it's the polarization film that was damaged here. This means that repair would be difficult, but if you had a really expensive screen and didn't want to replace it, you could potentially remove the polarization film layer and replace it.

Comment: You've learned about monitor construction, but that's a long way from repair.  1) You would need access to the film (in a 1 screen sized amount), which isn't readily available.  The polarization film isn't necessarily the outermost layer, so you may need other films, as well.  2) You would need a way to cleanly remove all film layers from the polarization layer out without causing any other layers below it to separate.  3) You would need equipment to bond the replacement layers.  They make vacuum autoclaves for repairing cellphone-sized screens, but I'm not aware of ones for a monitor.

Comment: You can get the film on amazon/ebay, and i've seen DIY videos for it on youtube.  It's not ideal but it's doable.  Polarization film doesn't even need to be directly on the panel, it could be a thick piece of film just taped on top if you really wanted and have the same effect (as long as it's polarized the right direction).

I never said it was ideal, just that it's possible.

Answer (score 3):

**Repair**

There is not a practical way to fix that and you are likely to make it worse by trying.

If the hole is only in a thin surface film, you might be able to press it flat, but if the film has been distorted (stretched), it probably won't stay flat.  You might find that over time, the film may flatten a little on its own.  I would not try to soften it with heat because some plastics will shrink and shrivel, making it worse and eliminating any chance for improvement.

If it is a puncture hole that extends into other plastic layers, you will not be able to flatten the raised rim of the hole without damaging a bigger area.

In terms of filling the hole, that is also likely to make it worse and if not, probably won't improve it.  It also depends on the purpose of the surface film and the cause of the bright spot.  If it is an anti-glare film,the bright spot may be the next layer.  Anything that is not anti-glare film will be a similarly non-diffusing surface.  If the filler doesn't have the same refractive index as the next layer, it may create cloudiness or distortion that will also be noticeable.

Filling the hole with something like what is used to fill holes in car windshields is likely to make it much worse.  That material is similar to superglue.  It may etch the surface.  It may wick under the film and damage a large area.  The fumes may etch the surface over a large area.

Similarly, trying to glue down the surface film may wick under the film and mess up a large area.  If you use an adhesive that doesn't wick, you would need a way to compress the film flat until it cures to avoid a permanent bump.  Material thick enough not to wick is likely to leave a raised area.  The screen sandwich is manufactured using tightly stretched sheets of material that are compressed together and bonded under pressure.  It is not a condition you can reproduce to repair a spot.

If you aren't satisfied with your repair result, you won't be able to undo it without making it worse than it was when you started.

**Symptom reduction**

There isn't a practical way to actually repair it, but can you make it less noticeable?  A number of people responded with ideas based on the principle that a dark spot may be less noticeable than a bright spot.  You could potentially make it a little less noticeable, but it's a question of how much improvement can you achieve and at what risk.

No matter what you do, it will still be noticeable.  Maybe a darker spot won't bother you as much if you get it right.  But there is a good chance of achieving little or no net improvement, and a substantial risk of making the situation worse in a non-fixable way.

Anything hard, like a pencil or pen tip, can nudge more film loose, making the hole bigger.  Any liquid can wick under the film, leaving a big stained area.  Assume permanent markers that will stick to the film will be permanent, whether or not it turns out to be an improvement.

Don't count on a redo or cleanup, because cleaning fluids, including any dissolved materials, can wick under the film, and rubbing is likely to make the hole bigger.  So if you don't get it as good as you're going to get it on the first try, you have a good chance of making the problem permanently worse.

Now that you've been forewarned, if you are determined to try this, here's an approach I would try if it was a last resort (disclaimer, I've never tested it, but it seems like the least risky alternative).  Practice the procedure first on something else to get the feel for how things behave and how much working time you have. Work with a magnifier and good light so you can see what you're doing.  Do the procedure with the screen lying face up and level.

Use a very viscous sticky material with temporary adhesion, like rubber cement for paper.  Use an extremely fine-tipped brush, or be extremely gentle with a toothpick, to apply a thin layer to the hole, being careful not to get it anywhere else (not getting it anywhere else is more important than perfectly filling the hole).

While it is still tacky, dust on some dry powdered graphite using a pinpoint applicator (sold in hardware stores as a lock lubricant).  Use a soft brush and blowing, while protecting the hole, to remove any graphite that lands outside the hole (you can clean the rest of the screen as you normally would, just be careful to avoid the hole).  If you've made the problem worse, you may be able to carefully peel this filler off when it dries.

If the hole bothers you so much that you are ready to replace the screen or buy a new monitor, you don't have much to lose by attempting these measures (other than possibly not having the monitor as a backup in the latter case).  Otherwise, consider whether the risks outweigh the minor potential improvement.

**Best solution?**

Unfortunately, this is one of those problems where the best solution may be to change how you view the problem.  You're aware of the hole, which serves as a constant reminder.  Instead of letting the hole bother you, think about how much money you will save by simply living with it.  Every time your eye is drawn to it, remind yourself of the savings from not buying a replacement monitor. :-)

Comment: Change your background to a light color.

Answer (score 0):

This morning I rubbed black shoe polish on a puncture similar to what you describe. I did it little by little, better too little than too much. At viewing distance it appears completely resolved.

Answer (score 0):

My repair to the  tv screen film consisted of blue pen ink mixed with thiners and touched in with a model detail brush.
Not perfect but not anywhere near as noticeable as the white light coming from behind the puntured film.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on my Sony 75 inch LED TV. A piece of polarizer film flaked off and left a pinhead sized “hole” where unfiltered bright white light shines constantly. It is very noticeable in any scene that is not practically white in that area of the screen. Prior posters noted that a black dot is better than a white one in general and I tested that by adhering a small piece of dark felt/fuzz to the hole and it helped a lot except during very light scenes.

I ultimately resolved the issue with polarizing film and rubber cement from Amazon for about $20. Rubber cement rubs off easily so it will not permanently damage the screen.

1. Cut a square piece of polarizer film to match the hole size. This will likely be quite small and I found that a slightly oversize patch is fine.
2. While holding the patch with tweezers, apply a very small amount of rubber cement to the patch.
3. Carefully orient the patch over the hole to filter the bright white light. You may need to rotate it 90 degrees one way or the other. If it is incorrectly oriented all light will pass through.
4. Apply the patch to the hole and press it in place in the correct light filtering orientation.

This worked very well for my issue and I have a lifetime supply of polarizing film and rubber cement on hand if I need to refresh the repair. The patch is barely noticeable even in very light scenes.

Comment: Hi Rob, would it be possible to post a picture of the result?

Answer (score -1):

This happened to my 60" TV screen - a very small hole in the first layer of the LCD screen.  I was able to make the hole a little less noticeable by very gently using a graphite pencil to fill in the hole.  it created a little bit of shading to filter the amount of light coming through.  Not by any means a fix, but slight improvement.

Answer (score -2):

I noticed that a white dot in a black image, it troubles more than a black dot in white image. after many experiments with pencils, or children's paints that dissolve in water, as well as vaseline and silicone, I got the best result with blue ink from an ordinary ballpoint pen diluted in pharmacy alcohol. depending on the dilution, it is possible to adjust the transparency of that paint in order to obtain a common fill.